# Almost having invariant vectors vs having almost invariant vectors?

Tags: operator-theory, representation-theory, c-star-algebras

Let $\Gamma$ be a discrete and countable Group and let $\pi:\Gamma\to \mathcal{B(H)}$ be a unitary representation.

We say that $\pi$ almost has invariant vectors if for every compact (=finite) subset $F\subseteq\Gamma$ and $\varepsilon >0$ there there exists a unit vector $\xi\in\mathcal{H}$ such that
$$ \|\pi(s)\xi -\xi\|<\varepsilon\; : \forall s\in F.$$

This is demonstrated to be equivalent to the weak containment of the trivial representation, denoted by $1_\Gamma$, in $\pi$ (see for example Cor. F.1.5, [1], general case of locally compact groups).

In other literature (for example Thm. A.5. and A.12, [2]) I have found the following definition:
$(\pi,\mathcal{H})$ admits almost invariant vectors if there exists a sequence of unit vectors $(\xi_n)_n\subseteq \mathcal{H}$ such that
$$\|\pi(s)\xi_n-\xi_n\| \to 0 \; : \; \forall s \in \Gamma$$
which is also claimed to be equivalent to the trivial representation being weakly contained in $\pi$.

Are these conditions really equivalent? If so, how would I go about understanding this equivalence? At this point I don't see how these two could be equivalent, without considering nets instead of sequences in the second condition.

Many thanks in advance.

---

[1] "Kazhdan’s Property (T)" by B. Bekka, P. de la Harpe and A. Valette)

[2] "Amenability of discrete groups by examples"
by Kate Juschenko

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implication "$(\pi, H)$ admits almost invariant vectors" $\Rightarrow$ "$(\pi,H)$ almost admits invariant vectors"  is relatively straightforward:  Choose a sequence $(\xi_n)$ in $H$ with $\|\pi(s)\xi_n-\xi_n\|\to 0$ for all $s\in\Gamma$.  If $F\subset\Gamma$ is finite and $\varepsilon>0$ is given, then for each $s\in F$ there is some $N_s$ such that $\|\pi(s)\xi_n-\xi_n\|<\varepsilon$ for $n\geq N_s$.  Now choose $n\geq\max\{N_s:s\in F\}$, and put $\xi=\xi_n$.

For the other direction, let $(F_n)$ be an increasing sequence of finite subsets of $\Gamma$ such that $\cup_nF_n=\Gamma$.  For each $n$, there exists $\xi_n\in H$ with $\|\pi(s)\xi_n-\xi_n\|<\frac{1}{n}$ for all $s\in F_n$.  Then $(\xi_n)$ is your sequence for the criterion of almost invariant vectors.